# open in a new page carrying same value as in base page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a jsp page, `insert.jsp`, and it has a submit button. When submit is clicked I want to display another page, `confirminsert.jsp`, and echo back the values that the user entered on `insert.jsp`. How do I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript/jQuery for this. Your `insert.jsp` page should have a form element that contains the inputs that the user enters values in. On submit these become request parameters that `confirminsert.jsp` can access in server-side code and it can then echo the values back out again.

You don't say what sort of JSP framework (if any) that you're working with so I'll stick to a really basic example:

In `insert.jsp`:

```
<form action="confirminsert.jsp" method="post" target="_blank">
    <label>Field One: <input name="field1" /></label>
    <label>Field Two: <input name="field2" /></label>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In `confirminsert.jsp`:

```
Field One: <%= request.getParameter("field1") %>
Field Two: <%= request.getParameter("field2") %>
```

As you can see, the names passed to the `request.getParameter()` function are the same as the names of the input fields.

Comment: ok but how can i open confirminsert.jsp in a new window after clicking submit button?

Comment: Sorry, your question didn't say anything about opening in a new window (even before I edited it to remove all the repetition). You can add `target="_blank"` to your form as per my updated sample code.